# i have problem with laravel fileupload image

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, laravel-8

can someone help me, i want to add article with image. image has successfully entered the directory but in the database the name is always D:\xampp\tmp\php......tmp.

I have changed the system file to public.

**Controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        $validateData = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'thumbnail' => 'image|file|max:8192',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($request->file('thumbnail')) {
            $imageName = time().'.'.$request->file('thumbnail')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $validatedData['thumbnail'] = $request->thumbnail->move(public_path('uploads/article/'), $imageName);
        }
             
        //dd($validateData['thumbnail']);
        Article::create($validateData);
        return redirect('/admin-article')->with('success', 'Data has been successfully added');
    }
```

Comment: You're using `move()` method which returns true if success, false otherwise. So basically, you're storing `$validatedData['thumbnail']` boolean value. I suggest use `storeAs()` method instead. It returns the path that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answer my problem has been solved with code like this, but only the name of the file stored in the database not with the name of the directory.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validateData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'thumbnail' => 'image|file|max:8192',
        'slug' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);
    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->thumbnail->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->thumbnail->move(public_path('articles/'), $imageName);
    $Article = new Article;
    $Article->title = $validateData['title'];
    $Article->thumbnail =  $imageName;
    $Article->slug = $validateData['slug'];
    $Article->description  = $validateData['description'];
    $Article->save();

    return redirect('/admin-article')->with('success', 'Data has been successfully added');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($request->file('thumbnail')) {
   $imageName = time().'.'.$request->file('thumbnail')->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $request->thumbnail->move(public_path('uploads/article/'), $imageName);
   $validatedData['thumbnail'] = url('uploads/article/'.$imageName);
}
```

The reason why it's return a path instead of url because you're using public_path instead of url()

Answer (score 0):

Controller Code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validateData = $request->validate([
        'title'       => 'required|max:255',
        'thumbnail'   => 'image|file|max:8192',
        'slug'        => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Check if request has file
    if($request->hasFile('thumbnail')){
        // Get File
        $file = $request->file('thumbnail'); 
        // Get File Extention
        $fileGetFileExtension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        // Create customized file name
        $fileName = Str::random(20).'_'.date('d_m_Y_h_i_s').'.'.$fileGetFileExtension; 
        // Save File to your storage folder
        Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads/article/'.$fileName,File::get($file));
    }else{
        $fileName = null;
    }

    $validatedData['thumbnail'] = $fileName;

    Article::create($validateData);

    return redirect('/admin-article')->with('success', 'Data has been successfully added');
}
```

Run `php artisan storage:link`, if not created

In blade you can get your file like this

```
<a href="{{ url('storage/uploads/article/'.$actical->thumbnail) }}"></a>
```

I hope this helps. :D